# Uploading files and JSON data in the same request express node js

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I have the below form written in JADE

```
<form id="formAddchallandetails" action="/adddata" method="post" name="adduser">
    <input id="inputunloadingDestination1" type="text" name="finalchallan[1][unloadingDestination]" placeholder="unloading Destination"> 
    <input id="inputCCNFForm1" type="text" name="finalchallan[1][CCNFForm]" placeholder=" Challan Number">
    <input id="inputtollCopy1" type="file" name="finalchallan[1][tollCopy]" > 

    <input id="inputunloadingDestination1" type="text" name="finalchallan[2][unloadingDestination]" placeholder="unloading Destination">
    <input id="inputCCNFForm2" type="text" name="finalchallan[2][CCNFForm]" placeholder=" CCNF form">
    <input id="inputtollCopy2" type="file" name="finalchallan[2][tollCopy]" >
    <button id="btnSubmit" type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

I want this form to post data of files and other arrays as JSON object in Express.js

My app.js

```
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));//set to true for passing array objects from form to route
    app.use(cookieParser());
    app.use(bodyParser({ keepExtensions: true, uploadDir: "uploads" }));
```

My index.js

```
router.post('/adddata', function(req, res) {
console.log("body");
console.log(req.body);
console.log("files");
console.log(req.files);

});
```

Output received is:

```
body
  {
    finalchallan: 
    [
        { 
            unloadingDestination: 'sdcsdf',       
            CCNFForm: 'zsd',
            tollCopy:'abc.txt',      
        },
        { 
            unloadingDestination: 'sdcsdf',       
            CCNFForm: 'zsd',       
            tollCopy:'xyz.txt',
        }
    ],
    tollCopy: '' }
files
undefined
```

Expected output is to receive JSON data as shown above and to receive all the file data with filename, tmpname etc to save the file in a directory.
Currently I am only getting the file name.

Options tried:

If I use **multer** and/or change the form **enctype="multipart/form-data"** than it does not pass my JSON data in object form rather it consider it as string.

Comment: did you get solution?

Answer (score 8):

Is not intended to combine multiple content types on the same request, if you send an `application/json` content type the server will expect all the data to be in that format. So, the file content will not be processed by the parser. One option is to use `multipart/form-data` and send your JSON data as string, and then, using `JSON.parse()`, convert it to JSON in the server. Another option is to separate your file upload in another route. And send two separated requests for this purpose.